# Sending GPS data through GPRS to a server

Tags: c#, java, gps, gprs

Please consider a  small car tracker project.

A GPS device is installed on each car, which sends data through the GPRS to a server.

Would you please tell me, what GPS deceive needed, that can be able to send data through GPRS ? And how I can use a regular SIM-CARD, to use it's GPRS to send data to a server ?

What about programming ? Both C# and Java, are OK.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a search on the internet for the TK-102 series of GPS trackers - or any of the clones.

These can be remotely configured by sending commands through SMS, and can report back locations both through SMS and TCP/IP over GPRS to the server you set up. Geofencing and variable triggers for location reporting can be configured.